# asp.net div.InnerHtml does not work with firefox a

Tags: asp.net

I want to update the content of a div in code behind:

```
StringWriter stringWriter = new StringWriter();

HtmlTextWriter htmlWriter = new HtmlTextWriter(stringWriter);

// adding new contents for htmlWriter

// update the div content
divBuilder.InnerHtml = stringWriter.ToString();
```

THe divBuilder is simply a html div:

```
<div id="divBuilder" runat="server"></div>
```

It works fine with IE and Chrome. Event it works well with Firefox in localhost but after uploading the website on the server, I got this error:

```
cannot get inner content of divBuilder because the contents are not literal
```

Searching on some sites, I came to this one: http://forums.asp.net/t/1168614.aspx/1
But then how to update the content?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you post the relevant markup?

Comment: divBuilder is simply a div html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the [HtmlContainerControl.InnerText](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.htmlcontrols.htmlcontainercontrol.innertext%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) property instead since you are using a string for the content.

Comment: but I would like to update the content so I have to use InnnerHtml, right?

Comment: What is the difference when it's a string?